# Property file is not loading in executable jar

Tags: maven, jar, executable, properties-file

I have property file in my maven project. Its in resources folder and below is snippet for that.

```
try
        {
            prop = new Properties();

           String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/src/test/resources/config/my.properties";
 
           FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream(path);
                  
            prop.load(propFile);
           

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO");
        }
```

in my maven project I have this file at given location in code. When am running this code in eclipse its working fine but when am creating executable jar am getting below error

```
 java -jar CRDPOM.jar
 File name ***  /Users/myuser/Documents/Personal-Workspace
 path :  /Users/myuser/Documents/Personal-Workspace/src/test/resources/config/my.properties
file not found
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite

**** browser name if *****  null
```

What am I missing here?

I checked it locally in eclipse and its working fine.

Comment: You should go vie `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/...")` instead... that will work during the build (unit-/and/or integration tests) as well as in production mode from within a jar file...

Comment: I tried this approach also but am getting resource null  URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
           System.out.println("url " +url);
 
           InputStream propFile1= getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

Comment: I wrote `getClass()..` and not `getClass().getClassLoader()`... Using it like this: `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/File")`...